# Si può dire "aver piacere a" in italiano?

Tags: grammar

Salve,
è corretta l'espressione "aver piacere a" seguita dall'infinito in italiano?
Per esempio, "se hai avuto piacere a leggere questo libro, te ne potrei consigliare un altro simile".
So che "provare piacere a" è corretto, mi chiedevo appunto se fosse possibile sostituire "provare" con "avere".
Grazie mille!

Comment: Io direi "avere piacere di", non "a"...

Comment: https://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_1704.html

Answer (score 2):

È sempre difficile dire se un'espressione è “corretta” in italiano: non c'è una norma univoca scolpita nella pietra. Anche a me personalmente, come osservato nei commenti, verrebbe più spontaneo usare “avere piacere di”.

D'altro canto, consultando Google Books e altro, anche escludendo per scrupolo traduzioni e autori troppo recenti, si trovano vari esempi di buoni scrittori che usano “avere piacere a”, e quindi direi che autorizzino anche noi a farlo.

Per esempio:

- Carlo Goldoni: “Questi è il primo forestiere capitato alla mia locanda, il quale non abbia avuto piacere a trattare con me” (*La locandiera*, atto I, scena 9, come si legge [qui](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Scelta_completa_di_tutte_le_migliori_com/gWk9AAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22avuto+piacere+a%22&pg=PA122&printsec=frontcover), ma altre edizioni riportano “piacere di”)
- Francesco Algarotti: “Tu puoi credere se io ho avuto piacere a vedere che l'ode tua piaccia ad altri che a me...” ([lettera del 1.7.1732](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Opere_Edizione_novissima_Con_memorie_int/OwtLAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22avuto+piacere+a%22&pg=PA275&printsec=frontcover))
- Cesare Beccaria: “Avrei piacere a sentirlo” e, poco più avanti, “Se non ti dispiace, avrei piacere a saperlo” (all'interno di *Della commedia presso i Greci, i Latini, e gl'Italiani*, Beccaria sta citando un [brano del *Trinummo* di Plauto](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Della_commedia_presso_i_Greci_i_Latini_e/IpZhAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22avrei+piacere+a%22&pg=PA283&printsec=frontcover), presumibilmente tradotto da lui)
- Giuseppe Giusti: “Non vi so dire quanto avrei piacere a trovarmi riveduto le bucce a modo e a verso, cosa che fa tanto pro a chi sa profittarne e che io non ho mai potuto ottenere” ([lettera del 17.2.1845](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Epistolario_di_Giuseppe_Giusti_ordinato/XSHKcAjxqY4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22avrei+piacere+a%22&pg=PA71&printsec=frontcover))
- Igino Ugo Tarchetti: “Ho piacere che tu, che altri lo sappiano, come si ha piacere a far conoscere, e a conoscere una buona azione.” (*Fosca*)
- Luigi Pirandello: “che vuoi che abbia piacere, io, a fare la signora!” (*Diana e la Tuda*, atto III)
- Mario Praz: “Grazie ... pel ricordo che Basilio ha consegnato a Clotilde ... Avrei avuto piacere a rivederlo” ([cartolina del 5.12.1975](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Mario_Praz_1896_1982/WJPNCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22avuto+piacere+a%22&pg=PA68&printsec=frontcover))